# type parameter bounds compiler error while pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-parameter

Why does the line

```
case Wrapper(rv: Ref[_]) => rv :: state
```

Not compile if

```
def f(r: Ref[_]): List[Ref[_]] = r :: state
```

compiles just fine?

Is there a way to get this code to compile while preserving as much type safety as possible ?

These lines are taken from the following self contained example:

```
object Test2 {

  trait Entity[T <: Entity[T]]


  case class Ref[T <: Entity[T]](t: T)

  type State[T <: Entity[T]] = List[Ref[T]]

  private var state: State[_] = ???

  trait SomeWrapper
  case class Wrapper[T <: Entity[T]](at: Ref[T]) extends SomeWrapper

  def matcher(w: SomeWrapper): Unit = w match {
    case Wrapper(rv: Ref[_]) => rv :: state // does not compile
    case _ => ???
  }

  def f(r: Ref[_]): List[Ref[_]] = r :: state // if this compiles fine, why the above does not compile ?


}
```

the code above gives the following compiler error:

```
Error:(40, 36) type arguments [Any] do not conform to class Ref's type parameter bounds [T <: Test2.Entity[T]]
    case Wrapper(rv: Ref[_]) => rv :: state // does not compile
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `f` escapes the typer checker, but when you try to *call* `f`, you'll get a compilation error for `T ` which doesn't `<: Entity[T]`.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do but it smells, badly. You're using f bounded type params on the state variable to retain type refinement information but then willingly dropping it with an existential type on your match? That's probably not going to give you what you want.

Comment: And [here is a minimal reproduce](https://gist.github.com/YuvalItzchakov/0b6838c67afab745e80826d00d51fd5d).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov That's because it makes no sense for the op to use f bounded polymorphism in an attempt to retain type refinement to then drop it by mixing in an existential. I'd expect a KList for this, a normal List will by design infer the type to `Any`, it should infer to `Ref[Any]` but I don't disagree with the compiler here necessarily.

Comment: @flavian Lets set a side the fact this might not be the best way to do what OP wants. I still don't understand, `Any` (or `Ref[_$3] forSome { type _$3 }`) isn't a subtype of `Entity[T]`, how is this compiling at all?

Comment: @flavian hmm, I don't try to retain the type info in `State`, I just want to express that `State` takes an `Entity`, any entity, such that the list can have any entities in it, but the type parameter for `State` should be and could be tighter than just an `Any`

Comment: maybe subtyping could another way to go, but I really don't like subtyping ... not very functional - and all that variance is going on my nerves...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me:

```
w match {
  case Wrapper(rv)         => (rv: Ref[_]) :: state // Compiles
  case Wrapper(rv: Ref[_]) => (rv: Ref[_]) :: state // Compiles
  case Wrapper(rv)         => rv           :: state // Doesn't Compile
  case Wrapper(rv: Ref[_]) => rv           :: state // Doesn't Compile???
  case e: Wrapper[_]       => e.at         :: state // Compiles
  case _ => ???
}
```

Comment: what kind of bug? compiler bug?

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug, yes.

Comment: pretty interesting... it does not seem to be inferring the correct type?

Comment: What's surprising is that writing `rv: Ref[_]`, you would expect `rv` to have type `Ref[_]`, but apparently there is something more complicated going on...